# How to set individual Light Paths Max Bounces for Transparent?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency

In "Render Properties > Light Paths > Max Bounces", I can select all the passes I need for all the blend file.  Is there a way to configure this for each individual object?

For example:

- For OBJ1, I'd like the Transparent bounces to be 8.
- For OBJ2, I'd like the Transparent bounces to be 12.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this on a per-material basis with the *Light Path* node.

Use a *Mix Shader* to tell the node tree that any bounce after a certain threshold should use a different BSDF.

Here's a plane with one edge extruded a few times to overlap, with a *Solidify* modifier.  After 5 bounces the BSDF changes from a light blue to red.

[image]

Your settings in *Render Properties* just need to be high enough to support your shader graphs.

Comment: Thanks mate for your answer.
So is it possible I can just limit the ones I'm not using?
Like some of the materials will use 8 passes, but some of them will use 60?